# Converting back from Javascript to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion, tsc

Is there any way to transpile back the Javascript code to Typescript, which has already been transpile to Javascript, from Typescript using Typescript compiler? (Eg: tsc helloworld.ts)

The issue is I have transpile the typescript source code to plain js, in order to deploy. After months, I have lost my source code but got the deployed js project.

Comment: If you have mappings you can try.
See here https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#sourceMap

Comment: You can convert it but without any of the types. So, you'd need to annotate everything again and re-create the types, too. Also figure out all libraries and imports used. Probably re-write some code that TS changed during the compilation. It's not so much a "conversion back" as much as "take an existing JS codebase and convert it to TS".

Comment: I wonder if this is possible if there's generated `.d.ts` file

Comment: @captain-yossarian whats the step to convert if even its not very clean? Anyone found solution?

Answer (score 0):

How should the compiler know where you've setted which type? Obviously, he can't.
So that doesn't work, you just could duplicate your js-file and set types manually.